# How to hide and display checkmark on cell when UITableViewCell tapped?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm working on a UITableView that acts like checklist. I need to display checkmark when `UITableViewCell` tapped and hide the checkmark when UITableViewCell tapped again. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059704/uitableviewcell-checkmark-to-be-toggled-on-and-off-when-tapped-swift) solution but I couldn't build because of `var checked = [Bool]()` part. How can I solve it with another way?

**EDIT**
I've added the code below to cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if checked == true {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
            checked = false
        } else if checked == false {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            checked = true
        }
```

Comment: you may need to store your rows' important details in your model, like e.g. _title_, _subtitle_, ..., and even the _checkState_ value.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this : (Swift 3)

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            if self.selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath)
            {
                cell.accessoryType = .none
                self.selectedIndexPaths.remove(indexPath)
            }
            else
            {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark                    
                self.selectedIndexPaths.add(indexPath)
            }
            // anything else you wanna do every time a cell is tapped
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

- Add a `checked` property of type `Bool` to your model.
- In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` set the checkmark according to the property.
- When the cell is tapped toggle the property and reload the cell or table view.

Comment: I followed your instructions but in tableview cells came one checked and the other is checked and next one checked like +-+-+-+-+-+-. I've added the property as global and added the code that I've added in my post.

Comment: no, you have to add the `checked` property to the model which represents the data source of the table view to get individual values for each row.  If you're using a dictionary add a key `checked` with an `Bool` value, if you're using a custom class (recommended), add a property.

Comment: I'm loading datas from an array. What do you mean by model?

Comment: The type of the items in the array is the model