# Swift 3: Why cant I change cell.accessoryType and cell.textLabel in didDeselectRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, didselectrowatindexpath

I can not understand why I can not toggle a selected table row. 
I am successfully setting the accessoryType in didSelectRowAt.
But I can not seem to set the accessoryType to none in didDeselectRowAt.

[image]

my data:

```
serviceItems = ["Heater", "Air Conditioner", "Boiler", "Heat Pump"]
```

here are my tableview overrides:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    let serviceItem = serviceItems[indexPath.row] as! String
    cell.textLabel?.text = serviceItem
}

// does not remove checkmark
// does not change textLabel to "test" 
// DOES print "DESELECTING" (so I know its getting called)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.accessoryType = .none
    cell.textLabel?.text = "test"
    print("DESELECTING")
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UItableviewcell Checkmark to be toggled on and off when tapped SWIFT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059704/uitableviewcell-checkmark-to-be-toggled-on-and-off-when-tapped-swift)

Comment: @theMikeSwan u had the answer if you wanna post it

Answer (score 6):

Should have been using `tableView.cellForRow` instead of `tableView.dequeueReusableCell`

Changed:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
```

To:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

I put everything in the DidSelectRow see here :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        if self.selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath)
        {
            // Config Cell
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            self.selectedIndexPaths.remove(indexPath)
        }
        else
        {
            // Config Cell
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark                    
            self.selectedIndexPaths.add(indexPath)
        }
        // anything else you wanna do every time a cell is tapped
    }    
}
```